# How to resolve Internal Server Error on API

Tags: angular, api, internal-server-error

I'm new to Angular and got a project, already existing, to work on. I have an API built with Symfony and the client with Angular. I have a model called Quotation. When getting on the route quotation/{id} it usually works except for some quotation where I have this error:

```
GET http://api.local/api/quotations/1381 500 (Internal Server Error) core.js:12501 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://api.local/api/quotations/1381", ok: false, …}
data: {data: {…}, notifications: Array(0)}
error: {data: {…}, notifications: Array(0)}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://api.local/api/quotations/1381: 500 Internal Server Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
repeatRequest: ƒ (newRequest)
request: HttpRequest {url: "http://api.local/api/quotations/1381", body: null, reportProgress: false, withCredentials: false, responseType: "json", …}
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://api.local/api/quotations/1381"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

I can't find differences between those who workd and those who doesn't. When I try to access it using the API and not the client I have this error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
      "@type": "hydra:Error",
      "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
      "hydra:description": "Notice: Trying to get property 'response' of non-object",
```

As I said I'm new to Angular and I don't know where to look, so I'll give you some of code where the error is triggered in the client.
quotation.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        map(params => params.get('quotationId')),
        withLatestFrom(this.route.queryParamMap),
        switchMap(data => {
          if (!!data[1].get('sync') && data[1].get('sync') === 'true') {
            return this.quotationService.syncQuotation(+data[0]);
          }
          return this.quotationService.get(+data[0]);
        }),
        map(data => {
          console.log(data);
          if (!data['@id']) {
            this.router.navigate(['/devis', +data.id]);
            return data;
          }
          return data;
        }),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectQuotationState))),
        switchMap(data => {
          this.isFav = !!data[1].favorites.find(element => element.id === data[0].id);
          this.quotation = data[0];
          console.log(this.quotation);
          return this.quotationService.getJobs(data[0]);
        }),
        switchMap((jobs: QuotationJob[]) => {
          this.jobs = jobs;
          return this.quotationService.search(this.quotation.clientName);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((searchResults: Quotation[]) => {
        this.searchResults = searchResults;
      });
  }
```

The line " return this.quotationService.get(+data[0]);" calls the quotation.service.ts:

```
get(id: number): Observable<Quotation> {
    return this.rg.one('quotations', id).get();
  }
```

For exemple if I ask id 2, it will work fine, I'll get the data I want but if I ask id 4, it'll trigger the error, when both id 2 and 4 are in the database ! I don't know what to do.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular, it's a backend problem. Perhaps you're request is invalid? Have you checked the request info in the browser developer tools?

Comment: Does your request work when sending it from Postman? As Daniel said, it's a backend issue and the first step would be to try to reproduce it (ie classic debugging).

Comment: I did check the request info but I can't see what's wrong.
When I do it in postman I also get the error "Notice: Trying to get property 'response' of non-object". And if I do it with another ID I get the right data.

Comment: You should debug on the server. If the very same code works for id 2 but doesn't for id 4, the error is most likely on the server (maybe some inconsistencies in the data ...)